# How to get files that are dragged on Aquamacs (or opened via Quicksilver) to open in the same frame

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs

In Aquamacs 2.0 preview 6, when opening new files externally (e.g., via Quicksilver or via dragging files on the Aquamacs icon) they always open in new frames (i.e., new windows).

I would prefer new files to be opening in the same frame, just in a new buffer (possibly with tabs turned on).

I already unchecked the option "Show Buffers in new Frames", but that only seems to affect the behavior of the built-in open command (Command-o).

Are there any options for this or some other way to modify this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Write this on your scratch file (the one that opens when you open emacs):

(setq dnd-open-file-other-window nil)

then leave the prompt just after the last parenthesis and presss C-x C-e. This will execute the command to toggle that variable. Make sure you save your options when you leave emacs so that next time you open it you won't have to do it again.